# Multiplication without operators in C# MSCorLib?

Tags: c#, mscorlib

I was digging through the MSCoreLib and I came across something interesting.

I am confused how this even works.

(ref http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs line 32)

```
   // This table is required for the Round function which can specify the number of digits to round to
      private static double[] roundPower10Double = new double[] { 
          1E0, 1E1, 1E2, 1E3, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6, 1E7, 1E8,
          1E9, 1E10, 1E11, 1E12, 1E13, 1E14, 1E15
      };          

      public const double E  = 2.7182818284590452354;
```

It appears they are creating a double array. Then, for each value multiplying `1 * E * nth`. That's what APPEARS to be happening however they aren't using any operators?

What is this dark magic?

Comment: How *what* works? What are you referring to, except for that array and that E?

Comment: No. It's allowed by syntax, you can use it normally inside your code: `var myDouble = 1e3`. It bassicaly means (e is shortcut for "exponent"): `1 * 10 ^ 3`.

Comment: I guess you were confused because you found a constant named `E`. But the `E` in the array is not the name of that constant. It is a literal notation meaning `x 10 ^`. Since it is a literal it is not a multiplication either. It is directly compiled into a certain number.

Comment: BTW: Do not mess that `e` with const decalared in source code you have pasted. There are two separate things.

Comment: @pwas so why does it have to be e? Can it be anything? can I do 1myVariableName3 ?

Comment: No no, read my later and @chiccodoro comment.

Comment: and the second one "E" is an Euler constant

Comment: @sasjaq it's not Euler constant (Euler's constant is equal to about 0,5) - it's Euler's number (base of natural logarithm)

Comment: @chiccodoro yup that's what was happening

Comment: @pwas oh, sure... the `public const` have misslead me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you're confused by the notation.

```
2e4 == 2E4 == 20000
```

simply means 2 * 10^4. `e` or `E` is the notation for "exponent". It is useful to prevent one from writing a lot of zeros. The second `E` has nothing to do with the first. The second is an identifier. But identifiers are not allowed in `double` literals (and literals in general).

**Example**:

say you wish to store the Avogadro constant, then you can write:

```
double Avogadro = 602300000000000000000000.0;
```

But it is confusing (since you need to count zeros and one can easily make a mistake). One can however write:

```
double Avogadro = 6.023e23;
```

Comment: Okay this is what I thought it was doing. I was just confused because they had a declaration of a variable right underneath the array with that exact variable name lol..

Answer (score 3):

This is [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). `1E2` means `1 * 10^2` or more generally, `xEy = x * 10^y`. You could also use a lowercase `e`.

The `public const double E  = 2.7182818284590452354` defined below is an unrelated (but very important!) [mathematical constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax "1E3" is just a short hand way of expressing `1 * 10^3`.   It is simply a compiler trick.  Note, However, that this is a *compile-time* constant.  You cannot use variables in there.  You can  however, use decimals : `2.57E4` = 25700.